planar_move_plugin and navigate to goal with unexpeceted behaviour
I'm developing a 4-wheel omni drive robot in a simulated environment, and I can teleoperate it with a joystick. However, when using nav2 for localization and autonomous navigation, it doesn't plan paths considering it's an omni robot. Additionally, the velocity commands are not optimal, and the robot constantly replans its path. Near the goal, it replans indefinitely and fails to achieve the objective. Supposedly, the nav2_params is correctly configured for the omni drive robot so I suspect the issue might be with the Planar Move Gazebo plugin. I provide the URDF, nav2 params and launch files if needed. Thanks in advance!
ROS2 HUMBLE
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
  ros__parameters:
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 100.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::OmniMotionModel" # omnidirectional nav2_amcl::OmniMotionModel
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.25
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: scan

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    wait_for_service_timeout: 1000
    action_server_result_timeout: 900.0
    navigators: ["navigate_to_pose", "navigate_through_poses"]
    navigate_to_pose:
      plugin: "nav2_bt_navigator::NavigateToPoseNavigator"
    navigate_through_poses:
      plugin: "nav2_bt_navigator::NavigateThroughPosesNavigator"
    # 'default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml' and 'default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml' are use defaults:
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_to_pose_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # They can be set here or via a RewrittenYaml remap from a parent launch file to Nav2.

    # plugin_lib_names is used to add custom BT plugins to the executor (vector of strings).
    # Built-in plugins are added automatically
    # plugin_lib_names: []

    error_code_names:
      - compute_path_error_code
      - follow_path_error_code

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    # controller server parameters (see Controller Server for more info)
    use_sim_time: True
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.001  # Holonomic Parameter
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    progress_checker_plugins: ["progress_checker"] # progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker" For Humble and older
    goal_checker_plugins: ["goal_checker"]
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    goal_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      stateful: True
    # DWB controller parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: -0.3
      min_vel_y: -0.3
      max_vel_x: 0.3
      max_vel_y: 0.3 # Holonomic Parameter
      max_vel_theta: 1.0
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.3
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
      # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 2.5 # Holonomic Parameter
      acc_lim_theta: 3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: -2.5 # Holonomic Parameter
      decel_lim_theta: -3.2
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 20 # Holonomic Parameter
      vtheta_samples: 20
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      # Holonomic Parameter
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist", "Twirling"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0
      Twirling.scale: 0.0

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      rolling_window: true
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
      robot_radius: 0.18
      plugins: ["voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.70
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      robot_radius: 0.18
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.7
      always_send_full_costmap: True

# The yaml_filename does not need to be specified since it going to be set by defaults in launch.
# If you'd rather set it in the yaml, remove the default "map" value in the tb3_simulation_launch.py
# file & provide full path to map below. If CLI map configuration or launch default is provided, that will be used.
map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    yaml_filename: ""

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    save_map_timeout: 5.0
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True

# planner_server:
#   ros__parameters:
#     planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
#     use_sim_time: True

#     GridBased:
#       plugin: "nav2_smac_planner/SmacPlanner2D" # In Iron and older versions, "/" was used instead of "::"
#       tolerance: 0.125                      # tolerance for planning if unable to reach exact pose, in meters
#       downsample_costmap: false             # whether or not to downsample the map
#       downsampling_factor: 1                # multiplier for the resolution of the costmap layer (e.g. 2 on a 5cm costmap would be 10cm)
#       allow_unknown: true                   # allow traveling in unknown space
#       max_iterations: 1000000               # maximum total iterations to search for before failing (in case unreachable), set to -1 to disable
#       max_on_approach_iterations: 1000      # maximum number of iterations to attempt to reach goal once in tolerance
#       max_planning_time: 2.0                # max time in s for planner to plan, smooth
#       cost_travel_multiplier: 2.0           # Cost multiplier to apply to search to steer away from high cost areas. Larger values will place in the center of aisles more exactly (if non-`FREE` cost potential field exists) but take slightly longer to compute. To optimize for speed, a value of 1.0 is reasonable. A reasonable tradeoff value is 2.0. A value of 0.0 effective disables steering away from obstacles and acts like a naive binary search A*.
#       use_final_approach_orientation: false # Whether to set the final path pose at the goal's orientation to the requested orientation (false) or in line with the approach angle so the robot doesn't rotate to heading (true)
#       smoother:
#         max_iterations: 1000
#         w_smooth: 0.3
#         w_data: 0.2
#         tolerance: 1.0e-10

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: True
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.5
      use_astar: false
      allow_unknown: true

planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    
# smoother_server:
#   ros__parameters:
#     smoother_plugins: ["simple_smoother"]
#     simple_smoother:
#       plugin: "nav2_smoother::SimpleSmoother"
#       tolerance: 1.0e-10
#       max_its: 1000
#       do_refinement: True

behavior_server:
  ros__parameters:
    local_costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    global_costmap_topic: global_costmap/costmap_raw
    local_footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    global_footprint_topic: global_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    behavior_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "drive_on_heading", "assisted_teleop", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/BackUp"
    drive_on_heading:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Wait"
    assisted_teleop:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/AssistedTeleop"
    local_frame: odom
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_tolerance: 0.1
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    loop_rate: 20
    stop_on_failure: false
    action_server_result_timeout: 900.0
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200


the urdf file:
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="morri">

    <xacro:arg name="use_ros2_control" default="false"/>
    <xacro:arg name="sim_mode" default="true"/>
    <!-- Xacro Properties for Easy Adjustments -->
    <xacro:property name="wheel_radius" value="0.03"/>
    <xacro:property name="wheel_width" value="0.03"/>
    <xacro:property name="wheel_mass" value="0.1"/>
    <xacro:property name="chassis_length" value="0.265"/>
    <xacro:property name="chassis_width" value="0.22"/>
    <xacro:property name="chassis_height" value="0.115"/>
    <xacro:property name="chassis_mass" value="0.5"/>
    <xacro:property name="wheel_base_front_offset" value="0.113"/> 
    <!-- This property defines the distance from the center of the robot to the front wheels along the length of the robot. In your robot's case, it indicates how far forward or backward the front wheels are positioned relative to the robot's center. -->
    <xacro:property name="wheel_track" value="0.095"/>
    <!-- The wheel_track property specifies the half-distance between wheels on the same axle from the centerline of the robot. Essentially, it's half the width between the left and right wheels on either the front or back axles, making it a critical measurement for understanding the robot's overall width and stability. -->
    <xacro:property name="wheel_axis_orientation" value="${pi/2}"/>

    <!-- Material Definitions -->
    <xacro:include filename="inertial_macros.xacro"/>
    <material name="white">
        <color rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
    </material>
    <material name="orange">
        <color rgba="1 0.3 0.1 1"/>
    </material>
    <material name="blue">
        <color rgba="0.2 0.2 1 1"/>
    </material>
    <material name="black">
        <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
    </material>
    <material name="red">
        <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
    </material>
    <material name="green">
        <color rgba="0 1 0 1"/>
    </material>

    <!-- Base Link -->
    <link name="base_link">
    </link>
    <joint name="base_footprint_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="base_footprint"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </joint>
    <link name="base_footprint">
    </link>

    <!-- Chassis Link -->
    <joint name="chassis_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="chassis"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
    </joint>
    <link name="chassis">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 ${chassis_height/2}"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="${chassis_length} ${chassis_width} ${chassis_height}"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="orange"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 ${chassis_height/2}"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="${chassis_length} ${chassis_width} ${chassis_height}"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_box mass="${chassis_mass}" x="${chassis_length}" y="${chassis_width}" z="${chassis_height}">
            <origin xyz="0 0 ${chassis_height/2}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_box>
    </link>
    <gazebo reference="chassis">
        <material>Gazebo/Green</material>
    </gazebo>

    <!-- Wheel Links and Joints -->
    <xacro:macro name="wheel" params="name joint_type parent_joint origin_x origin_y origin_z axis_x axis_y axis_z wheel_rotation">
        <joint name="${name}_joint" type="${joint_type}">
            <parent link="${parent_joint}"/>
        <child link="${name}"/>
            <origin xyz="${origin_x} ${origin_y} ${origin_z}" rpy="${wheel_axis_orientation} 0 0"/>
            <axis xyz="${axis_x} ${axis_y} ${axis_z}"/>
    </joint>
    <link name="${name}" type="wheel">
            <visual>
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}"/>
                </geometry>
                <material name="blue"/>
            </visual>
            <collision>
                <geometry>
                    <sphere radius="${wheel_radius}"/> 
                <!-- <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}"/> -->
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="${wheel_mass}" radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}">
                <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
        </link>
        <gazebo reference="${name}">
          <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
          <mu1 value="0.001"/>
          <mu2 value="0.001"/>
        </gazebo>
    </xacro:macro>

    <!-- Left Wheel -->                                                             <xacro:property name="wheel_x_origin" value="${wheel_base_front_offset - wheel_radius}"/>
<xacro:wheel name="rear_left_wheel" joint_type="continuous" parent_joint="base_link" origin_x="-${wheel_x_origin}" origin_y="${wheel_track}" origin_z="${wheel_radius}" axis_x="0" axis_y="0" axis_z="1" wheel_rotation="-1"/>

    <!-- Right Wheel -->
    <xacro:wheel name="rear_right_wheel" joint_type="continuous" parent_joint="base_link" origin_x="-${wheel_x_origin}" origin_y="-${wheel_track}" origin_z="${wheel_radius}" axis_x="0" axis_y="0" axis_z="1" wheel_rotation="1"/>

    <!-- Front Left Wheel -->
    <xacro:wheel name="front_left_wheel" joint_type="continuous" parent_joint="base_link" origin_x="${wheel_x_origin}" origin_y="${wheel_track}" origin_z="${wheel_radius}" axis_x="0" axis_y="0" axis_z="1" wheel_rotation="-1"/>

    <!-- Front Right Wheel -->
    <xacro:wheel name="front_right_wheel" joint_type="continuous" parent_joint="base_link" origin_x="${wheel_x_origin}" origin_y="-${wheel_track}" origin_z="${wheel_radius}" axis_x="0" axis_y="0" axis_z="1" wheel_rotation="1"/>

    <!-- Gazebo Plugin for Movement -->
    <gazebo>
        <plugin name="object_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_planar_move.so">
            <ros>
                <remapping>cmd_vel:=cmd_vel_out</remapping> 
            </ros> 
            <!-- twist recebe cmd_vel_joy e cmd_vel da nav2 (default) e cospe no /cmd_vel_out (default) -->
            <odometry_frame>odom</odometry_frame>
            <odometry_rate>20.0</odometry_rate>
            <odometry_topic>odom</odometry_topic>
            <robot_base_frame>base_link</robot_base_frame>
            
            <command_topic>cmd_vel</command_topic>
            <publish_odom>true</publish_odom>
            <publish_odom_tf>true</publish_odom_tf>
            <!-- <covariance_x>0.0001</covariance_x>
            <covariance_y>0.0001</covariance_y>
            <covariance_yaw>0.01</covariance_yaw> -->
            
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>

    <transmission name="front_left_wheel_transmission">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="front_left_wheel_joint">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="front_left_wheel_motor">
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>

    <transmission name="front_right_wheel_transmission">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="front_right_wheel_joint">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="front_right_wheel_motor">
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>

    <transmission name="rear_left_wheel_transmission">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="rear_left_wheel_joint">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="rear_left_wheel_motor">
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>

    <transmission name="rear_right_wheel_transmission">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="rear_right_wheel_joint">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="rear_right_wheel_motor">
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>

    <!-- DEPTH CAMERA -->
    <joint name="camera_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="chassis"/>
        <child link="camera_link"/>
        <origin xyz="0.1025 0 0.09" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="camera_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.010 0.03 0.03"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="red"/>
        </visual>
    </link>


    <joint name="camera_optical_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="camera_link"/>
        <child link="camera_link_optical"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${-pi/2} 0 ${-pi/2}"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="camera_link_optical"></link> 
    <!-- outra forma de olhar poara o mesmo link porque o standard de eixo de camaras e diferente do robo z para a frent x para a direta-->



    <gazebo reference="camera_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Red</material>

        <sensor name="camera" type="depth">
            <pose> 0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
            <visualize>true</visualize>
            <update_rate>10</update_rate>
            <camera>
                <horizontal_fov>1.089</horizontal_fov>
                <image>
                    <format>B8G8R8</format>
                    <width>640</width>
                    <height>480</height>
                </image>
                <clip>
                    <near>0.05</near>
                    <far>8.0</far>
                </clip>
            </camera>
            <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
                <frame_name>camera_link_optical</frame_name>
                <min_depth>0.1</min_depth>
                <max_depth>100.0</max_depth>
            </plugin>
        </sensor>
    </gazebo>

    <!-- LIDAR -->

    <!-- <xacro:include filename="rplidar.xacro"/> -->
    
    <joint name="laser_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="chassis"/>
        <child link="laser_frame"/>
        <origin xyz="-0.025 0 0.1415" rpy="0 0 0"/> 
    </joint>

    <link name="laser_frame">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.035" length="0.051"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="black"/>    
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.035" length="0.051"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="0.1" length="0.04" radius="0.05">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
    </link>


    <gazebo reference="laser_frame">
        <material>Gazebo/Black</material>

        <sensor name="laser" type="ray">
            <pose> 0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
            <visualize>true</visualize>
            <update_rate>10</update_rate>
            <ray>
                <scan>
                    <horizontal>
                        <samples>360</samples>
                        <min_angle>-3.14</min_angle>
                        <max_angle>3.14</max_angle>
                    </horizontal>
                </scan>
                <!-- confirmar range do lidar -->
                <range> 
                    <min>0.3</min>
                    <max>12</max>
                </range>
            </ray>
            <plugin name="laser_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_ray_sensor.so">
                <ros>
                    <argument>~/out:=scan</argument>
                </ros>
                <output_type>sensor_msgs/LaserScan</output_type>
                <frame_name>laser_frame</frame_name>
            </plugin>
        </sensor>
    </gazebo>

</robot>


And the launch file:

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription, TimerAction
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.actions import RegisterEventHandler, DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessStart
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, Command


def generate_launch_description():


    # Include the robot_state_publisher launch file, provided by our own package. Force sim time to be enabled
    # !!! MAKE SURE YOU SET THE PACKAGE NAME CORRECTLY !!!

    package_name='novamob' 

    rsp = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory(package_name),'launch','rsp.launch.py'
                )]), launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': 'true', 'use_ros2_control': 'true'}.items() # AQUI DEFINIMOS SE ESTAMOS EM SIMULACAO OU ROBO REAL
    )
    default_rviz_config_path = os.path.join(os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('novamob')), 'rviz','configV3.rviz')

    gazebo_params_file = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name),'config','gazebo_params.yaml')

    # Include the Gazebo launch file, provided by the gazebo_ros package
    gazebo = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'), 'launch', 'gazebo.launch.py')]),
                    launch_arguments={'extra_gazebo_args': '--ros-args --params-file ' + gazebo_params_file}.items()
             )

    # Run the spawner node from the gazebo_ros package. The entity name doesn't really matter if you only have a single robot.
    spawn_entity = Node(package='gazebo_ros', executable='spawn_entity.py',
                        arguments=['-topic', 'robot_description',
                                   '-entity', 'my_bot'],
                        output='screen')


    robot_description = Command(['ros2 param get --hide-type /robot_state_publisher robot_description'])

    controller_params_file = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name),'config','my_controllers.yaml')

    diff_drive_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["diff_cont"],
    )
    
    joint_broad_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["joint_broad"],
    )

    controller_manager = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        parameters=[{'robot_description': robot_description},
                    controller_params_file]
    )

    delayed_controller_manager = TimerAction(period=3.0, actions=[controller_manager])


    delayed_diff_drive_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessStart(
            target_action=controller_manager,
            on_start=[diff_drive_spawner],
        )
    )
    delayed_joint_broad_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessStart(
            target_action=controller_manager,
            on_start=[joint_broad_spawner],
        )
    )
    
    rviz_node = Node(
        package='rviz2',
        executable='rviz2',
        name='rviz2',
        output='screen',
        arguments=['-d', LaunchConfiguration('rvizconfig')],
    )

    joint_state_publisher_node = Node( 
        package='joint_state_publisher',
        executable='joint_state_publisher',
        name='joint_state_publisher',
        parameters=[
                {'use_sim_time': True}
            ]
        # condition=launch.conditions.UnlessCondition(LaunchConfiguration('gui'))
    )

    twist_mux_params = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name),'config','twist_mux.yaml')
    twist_mux = Node(
            package="twist_mux",
            executable="twist_mux",
            parameters=[twist_mux_params, {'use_sim_time': True}],
            # remappings=[('/cmd_vel_out','/diff_cont/cmd_vel_unstamped')] for ros2_control
        )

    # Launch them all!
    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument(name='rvizconfig', 
            default_value=default_rviz_config_path,
            description='Absolute path to rviz config file'),
        twist_mux,
        joint_state_publisher_node,
        rsp,
        rviz_node,
        gazebo,
        spawn_entity
        # delayed_controller_manager,
        # delayed_diff_drive_spawner,
        # delayed_joint_broad_spawner
    ])```

